# Read a Variable one time in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, variables, shared

I have 5 class variables to create a connection String, which I want to read just one time from the web.config file. This means I have to keep these variables.

Is This code below the best practice nowadays or are there better ways to do this?

A section from my code:

```
Public Class DBController
    Shared servername As String = getPropertyValue("Servername")
    Shared databas As String = getPropertyValue("Databas")
    Shared id As String = getPropertyValue("Id")
    Shared password As String = getPropertyValue("password")
    Shared security As String = getPropertyValue("security")

    Private Function getPropertyValue(key As String)
        Dim appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
        Dim configValue As Stirng = appSettings(key)
        Return configValue
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Configuration files are cached in .NET anyway. The only exception are configuration files of different projects.

Comment: Aside from the excellent point that Tim made, you could theoretically also use `Lazy(Of String)(Function() ...)` to do lazy-loading in .NET >4.

Comment: If you only have to call for them once, why not just assign the values directly to the property? Also if what you posted is the complete code you may find that creating a `Structure` will provide better performance. Side note: there is no such type as `Stirng`

Comment: You could look at the singleton pattern.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the singleton pattern, but i don't know how to implement it with vb.net.